# Prove ${2a \choose 2b} \equiv {a \choose b} \pmod 2$

Tags: modular-arithmetic, combinatorial-proofs

I want to prove

${2a \choose 2b} \equiv {a \choose b} \pmod 2$

with induction. I've seen one that uses the Iverson bracket notation, however that doesn't seem to fit into the scope of what I am learning right now. Is there another way to prove this?

Comment: Not that it matters if you don't want to use it, but do you mean the *Iverson* bracket?

Comment: You could try [Lucas' Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lucas%27s_theorem).

Comment: Yeah sorry I misspelled.

Comment: You can prove more generally that if $p$ is prime then $$\binom{pa}{pb}\equiv \binom{a}b\pmod{p^2}$$ But even more surprising is, the congruence is actually true $\pmod{p^3},$ when $p\geq 5.$

Answer (score 3):

You have $2a$ limes and you want to choose $2b$ of them. Divide your set into two buckets with $a$ limes in them a piece. A choice of $2b$ limes is called split if there are exactly $b$ limes in each bucket. Then ${a \choose b}^2$ gives the number of split choices. On the other hand, the number of non-split choices is even, because there is an involution of that set with no fixed-points given by flip-flopping the buckets.

So
$$
{2a \choose 2b} = {a \choose b}^2 + \text{ something even },
$$
which proves the result since ${a \choose b}^2$ has the same parity as ${a \choose b}$.

Answer (score 2):

Use Pascal's identity

$$\binom{n}{k}=\binom{n-1}{k-1}+\binom{n-1}{k} \, .$$

Apply this to $\displaystyle\binom{2a}{2b}$. Then apply it again to the two new binomial coefficients you just got. Then use the induction hypothesis.